# Read XML data into Javascript Node

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm trying to play around with creating my own XML to JSON converter. One problem, I can't seem to figure out how to read XML data in. The code below is a failed attempt to read it in from a string. Is there a way to read it in from a file as xml?

```
  function xmlToJson(xml) {

        // Create the return object
        var obj = {};

        debugger;
        if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
            // do attributes
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
            obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }

        return obj;
    };



    var xml = "<subject><story><unique_id>665c43</unique_id><story_url>http://this ismystory.com</story_url></story></subject>";


xmlToJson(xml);
```

Comment: There's no way that `xml.nodeType` will work since `xml` is just a `String`. You should find an XML library in `npm`. Note, I've found that they're all pretty terrible.

Comment: @Jacob - Thx, But i guess if i were to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml  that would take care or XMLtoJSON also (which I don't want)..i just want to be able to import XML. Is that true?

Comment: @Jacob - Have you tried xml-flow? I also found them all to be pretty terrible, so decided to build a better one: https://github.com/matthewmatician/xml-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try xml2js if you don't want to use jQuery.

Here is an example from the [xml2js github](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js):

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right before you call this function, add this line.

```
var xml = jQuery.parseXML(xml);
```

*Note: you might have to play with variable names.
Either way, the requirement is that the string must be converted to a `XMLObject`.*

See if that takes care of it for you.

Comment: i added- var jQuery = require('jQuery'); and   var xml = jQuery.parseXML(xml); and get....
                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function (refferring to .parseXML)

Comment: I'm new to JS with node, is there something special I need to do to add jQuery?

Comment: add this to the top of your html page in the <head> section   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i'm not using an  html page

Comment: ok.  Change up.  Look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gtLBx/15/  It uses the x2js library.  It eases the requirements on how to convert xml to json.  it should help.